# PowerShell: How to Batch Rename Using Split

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I'm new to PowerShell to try and Batch Rename files. I'm deleting unique fields from the file which I managed to Using Split. I can't figure out how to Rename them. This is how I got the file names to output how I want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Name | `
foreach {
$string = $_.split(" _ ")
$newName = $string[0] + " _ " + $string[2]
Write-Output $newName
}
```

I Split the file by the underscores and just used the 1st and 3rd Split. Can anyone please help using the split to Rename the files? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `Write-Output $newName` by
`Rename-Item $_ -NewName $newName`.

Reference :
[Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.4).

Comment: Thank you harrymc and lpchip it works great now. You have saved me alot of time renaming. Thanks again and much appreciated.

Comment: @KoKee: Have you encountered a problem, that you've revoked acceptance?

Comment: Sorry I must have accidentally unticked it. Works great 